# How would you go about reverting a single file to previous commit state using git?

Tags: git

I wonder why isn't it implemented in the GUI?
I know git has a content approach vs. single file approach but sometimes single file reverting is crucial.

For instance an .png graphics file from a few commits before is needed.

Probably I need to do a checkout but I'm still not sure as the concepts sometimes escape me.