# How can I check out a particular version of one file in Git?

Tags: git

How can I check out a particular version of one file in git?

I found [this mail on the mailing list](https://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2009/1/6/4608324/thread+git+checkout+a+file&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), which said:

```
$ git checkout HEAD~43 Makefile
$ git reset Makefile
```

But I don't understand how to find out 'HEAD~43', if I do a `git log aFile`, how can I find out which 'HEAD~43' I should use?

And why do I need to run `git reset` for that file? What does it do?

Comment: "git reset <commit> <file>" does exactly the same as "git checkout <commit> <file>".

Comment: If your question is about HEAD~43 syntax (documented in git-rev-parse), ask about this issue, not about unrelated one you know the answer to. "What does HEAD~45 mean, and how to find particular version of file"

Comment: according to http://www.lt.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.6.0.6/git-checkout.html and http://www.lt.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.6.0.6/git-reset.html, "git reset <commit> <file>" doesn't do exactly the same as "git checkout <commit> <file>": "git reset <commit> <file>" reverts <file> in the index from <commit> without touching <file> in the working tree, but "git checkout <commit> <file>" updates the index for <file> from <commit> and then updating <file> in working tree.

Comment: As T.J. suggested, please mark the answer below as accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Answer (score 118):

You know what commit (ie: the specific revision) the file belongs to? Then do:

```
git checkout <commit> <file>
```

The other command:

```
git checkout HEAD~N <file>
```

Is for when you want to get a version of the file from a range back (which I do for nostalgia).

Answer (score 20):

`HEAD~43` is just treeish, so you can use a hash or a tag. You have to separate treeish from the filename with `--`, otherwise it is treated as filename. For example.

```
git checkout v0.45 -- filename
git checkout HEAD^ -- filename
git checkout 16bb1a4eeaa9 -- filename
```

Answer (score 2):

`HEAD~43` refers to the commit (version) of the file. Instead of that, you can use the commit hash you get from doing `git log` on the file. If you just want the file, you don't need to run `git reset` on it; that's only necessary if you want to forward-port the file to the current HEAD.