# Fetch all the previous versions of any file committed in Git

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-commit, git-config

I want to fetch all the previous versions of a file (let's assume Abc.xml) that I've committed in Git.

Is there any way to do so? I am sure Git has versioning system and so what I feel that my older file versions can be available. Any suggestions?

Comment: The first suggestion: check **ANY** git tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the log of your file:

```
git log -- myFile
```

Or, for all branches:

```
gitk --all -- myFile
```

Then checkout (meaning replace in your current working tree) [your file with any past version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1173699/6309)

```
git checkout <commit> <file>
```

Or simply see it with [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show).

> I was getting error as : object file is empty

Then check out:

- [how to fix GIT error: object file is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11706215/6309)
- [Fix git error : object file is empty](https://gist.github.com/yblee85/0614f3021d21e2d47139)

Comment: I didn't know `gitk` took a filename parameter. Handy, thanks!

Comment: @Vonc I was getting error as : object file is empty.

Comment: @Ashraf.Shk786 with which git command, on which OS, using which shell? (and which git version?)

Comment: @Vonc its working fine. I've restarted my machine and now tried to use the same commands mentioned.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do:

```
git log Abc.xml
```

to get hashes of commits that change this file. Then, for each hash, you can show the change:

```
git show c0d235cae22540ef1bcd2a35dddd919166d45666
```

Most IDEs have this feature integrated as well. NetBeans has a very good interface to Git.