# How do I get a particular (older) version of a file from git repository without wiping out later versions?

Tags: git

I should think that getting a previous version is one of source control's premier features, and should be simple, yet it seems like a treasure hunt finding git solution.

I came across stackoverflow question [How can I check out a particular version of one file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173676/how-can-i-check-out-a-particular-version-of-one-file-in-git).  To paraphrase the key thing:

```
git checkout <commit hash from git log output>
```

As I expected it to happen, the file in the working directory was replaced/updated with the requested older version, but I lost the later versions in the repository, got a message like "... detached head...".

Any guiding principles here would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: as far as I understand you did not loose the later versions in the repository - check out the answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just use `git checkout <somehash>`, then you will get into a detached HEAD. This happens because `git checkout` by default just switches branches, and specifying a commit instead of a branch gets you into a “branchless mode” (that’s what detached HEAD means).

If you want to get a single file from a different version, you also need to specify the path, i.e. `git checkout <somehash> -- path/to/file`. This will keep everything as it is and just replace the file at `path/to/file` with its version from `<somehash>`.

So this does overwrite the file. If you want to keep the current version as well, you should rename it first. Otherwise, you can also use a special syntax of `git show` for this

```
git show <somehash>:path/to/file > new_filename.ext
```

This will essentially get the contents of the file from `<somehash>` and print it, so if you pipe it to file, you can extract a file from a different version into a different filename.

Comment: Thanks.  The special syntax of the show command addresses my problem.  I didn't want to change the state of the repository, I just wanted to get at the older version of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a special commit like `abc123456` and in that commit the file was good, you just need to ...

```
git checkout abc123456 path/to/file
```

with this command you will find in stage that version of the file.

You can also use branches:

```
git checkout old-branch-name path/to/file
```