# Revert changes to a file in a commit

Tags: git, version-control, revert

I want to revert changes made by a particular commit to a given file only.

Can I use git revert command for that?

Any other simple way to do it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git/215768

Comment: Strange... why the change after all those years?

Answer (score 368, accepted):

The cleanest way I've seen of doing this is described [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Revert-a-single-commit-in-a-single-file-tp6064050p6064406.html)

```
git show some_commit_sha1 -- some_file.c | git apply -R
```

Similar to VonC's response but using `git show` and `git apply`.

Comment: Nicely done. The script solution is overkill for this. Why can't there just be git revert sha-1 filename ?

Comment: This works on my Mac, but on Windows (under Cygwin) it gives me: `fatal: unrecognized input`

Comment: It only puts back the file from the index. I needed to then run `git checkout -- some_file.c ` to fully revert the file back.

Comment: @MerhawiFissehaye : I think git checkout will only revert the changes again  to fall back to the state what was in commit. I did 'git add filename ; git commit --amend' to remove the file from commit.

Comment: This works wonderfully, but are there any caveats to this approach vs @VonC's that are worth knowing?

Comment: Just a tip, I almost always have to add the `-3` flag to git apply for three-way merge when the patch fails, since I am usually correcting a change a bit back in time.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade same thing in Ubuntu. Turns out it was ANSI escape sequences for colors, once those were stripped, it worked

Comment: Maybe obvious to most but ensure `some_file.c` includes the *path* to the file if there is one otherwise you'll silently patch nothing :)

Comment: doesn't work for a binary file. Nevertheless, I copied original file back and did git add/git commit --amend.

Comment: If you get an `unrecognized input` on Windows, maybe you're simply using forward slashes in your filenames instead of backslashes. Also, quote each file if it's a list of files. So my command looked like: `git show 0fa42bec07005e47401ddba2e0e28f60cb034fa6 -- "app/js/controllers/file1.controller.js" "app/templates/views/file1.pug" "java/core/src/main/java/com/georgiecasey/file3.kt" | git apply -R`

Comment: To do this for the previous commit without looking up the exact commit hash, you can use `git show HEAD^{commit} -- [...]`; it doesn't seem to work with just `HEAD` without the `^{commit}` unfortunately.  (Windows users: the `^` also has to be escaped as `^^`)

Comment: What if you don't know the commit sha/s that made the changes?

Comment: @ScottyBlades https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame/2.31.0

Comment: i got this error
```error: patch failed: <file_name>:<line_number>
error: <file_name>: patch does not apply```

Answer (score 72):

Assuming it is ok to change the commit history, here's a workflow to revert changes in a single file in an earlier commit:

For example, you want to revert changes in 1 file (`badfile.txt`) in commit `aaa222`:

```
aaa333 Good commit
aaa222 Problem commit containing badfile.txt
aaa111 Base commit
```

Rebase on the base commit, amend the problem commit, & continue.

1) Start interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i aaa111
```

2) Mark the problem commit for edit in the editor by changing `pick` to `e` (for edit):

```
e aaa222
pick aaa333
```

3) Revert changes to the bad file:

```
git show -- badfile.txt | git apply -R
```

4) Add the changes & amend the commit:

```
git add badfile.txt
git commit --amend
```

5) Finish the rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Just want to point out that this assumes you can edit the git history. Some answers above create a new commit that reverses the particular change without editing the history, which is not always possible/allowed.

Comment: Fantastic. This was exactly what I was looking for. I had this idea already, but got confused when doing the interactive rebase that the files when doing the `edit` was not showing as changed. But the `git show -- badfile.txt | git apply -R` gave the answer I needed <3

Comment: if i understand this git apply -R  removes the commit on that file setting it back to the original changed state?

Comment: for android studio users, you can right click the file that you want to change, and click rebase and choose the branch that has the good code (probably develop) and click accept theirs to fetch all changes from their and ignore your changes.

Answer (score 27):

Much simpler:

```
git reset HEAD^ path/to/file/to/revert
```

then

```
git commit --amend
```

and then

```
git push -f
```

the file is gone and commit hash, message, etc is the same.

Comment: For completeness, do you need a `git checkout -- path/to/file/to/revert` step? Also, it is not true that the hash is the same afterwards, right? The last sentence might be better as something like: "The result is that the last commit is replaced by a new one that differs only in that it does not contain the changes to the reverted file."

Comment: @Kevin you're probably right. I'll have to double check that last line, but looking back at this from a couple years ago I'd be surprised if the commit hash is unchanged.

Answer (score 22):

[`git revert`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) is for all file contents within a commits.

For a single file, you can [script it](http://github.com/smtlaissezfaire/git-shell-scripts/blob/master/git-revert-single-file):

```
#!/bin/bash

function output_help {
    echo "usage: git-revert-single-file <sha1> <file>"
}

sha1=$1
file=$2

if [[ $sha1 ]]; then
git diff $sha1..$sha1^ -- $file | patch -p1
else
output_help
fi
```

(From the [git-shell-scripts](http://github.com/smtlaissezfaire/git-shell-scripts) utilities from [smtlaissezfaire](http://github.com/smtlaissezfaire))

---

Note:

another way is [described here](http://norbauer.com/notebooks/code/notes/git-revert-reset-a-single-file) if you have yet to commit your current modification.

```
git checkout -- filename
```

[`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) has some options for a file, modifying the file from HEAD, overwriting your change.

---

[Dropped.on.Caprica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23875/dropped-on-caprica) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620775/git-revert-changes-to-a-file-in-a-commit/2620822#comment47012308_2620822):

> You can add an alias to git so you can do `git revert-file <hash> <file-loc>` and have that specific file be reverted.
>   See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/droppedoncaprica/5b67ec0021371a0ad438).

```
[alias]
  revert-file = !sh /home/some-user/git-file-revert.sh
```

Comment: Just to add to the discussion here, you can add an alias to git so you can do `git revert-file <hash> <file-loc>` and have that specific file be reverted.  I lifted from this answer (though I had to make a couple edits to work correctly).  You can find a copy of my `.gitconfig` and edited script here:

https://gist.github.com/droppedoncaprica/5b67ec0021371a0ad438

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 21):

If you'd like to reset the changes on a file from your last commit, this is what I'm usually using. I think this is the simplest solution.

Please note that the file will be added to the staging area.

```
git checkout <prev_commit_hash> -- <path_to_your_file>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is the way to go if you aren't looking to rewrite history.  I've been using this to cleanup files I didn't really need to touch prior to a squash merge. Then the churn gets paved over anyway.

Comment: This will revert *all* the changes to the file since that commit, not a single commit

Comment: Correct words are "previous commit hash" not current commit. Thank you @Gabeeka

Comment: This should be the accepted and most rated answer.

Answer (score 13):

I would simply use the `--no-commit` option to `git-revert` and then remove the files you don't want reverted from the index before finally committing it. Here's an example showing how to easily revert just the changes to foo.c in the second most recent commit:

```
$ git revert --no-commit HEAD~1
$ git reset HEAD
$ git add foo.c
$ git commit -m "Reverting recent change to foo.c"
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

The first `git-reset` "unstages" all files, so that we can then add back just the one file we want reverted. The final `git-reset --hard` gets rid of the remaining file reverts that we don't want to keep.

Answer (score 11):

```
git reset HEAD^ path/to/file/to/revert/in/commit
```

The above command will take file out of commit, but it will reflect in `git status`.

```
git checkout path/to/file/to/revert/in/commit
```

The above command will revert the changes (as a result you get file same as HEAD).

```
git commit
```

(Pass `--amend` to amend commit.)

```
git push
```

With this, the file which is already in the commit is removed and reverted.

The above steps should be followed from the the branch where the commit is made.

Answer (score 8):

You can follow this procedure:

1. `git revert -n <*commit*>` (`-n` revert all the changes but won't 
   commit them)
2. `git add <*filename*>` (name of the file/s you want to revert & commit)
3. `git commit -m 'reverted message'` (add a message for reverting)
4. after committing discard the other files changes so the files stay 
   updated with the changes you committed before the revert