# Can `git checkout HEAD^ -- <file>` revert a file in a commit?

Tags: git

I am consider this question: [Revert changes to a file in a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620775/revert-changes-to-a-file-in-a-commit)

Can I just run `git checkout HEAD^ -- <file>` and then `git add <file>` and `git commit` to revert the change to a file in a commit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but note that `git checkout` first writes the file from the `<tree-ish>` argument *to* the index, *then* copies the updated index copy of the file to the work-tree:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- <file>
```

Now `<file>` is the same in the index and work-tree, and matches the version in the commit found by `HEAD^`.

Hence:

> and then `git add <file>`

is unnecessary, since this just copies the work-tree version into the index.<sup>1</sup>  You can just do the commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>The work-tree version already matches the index, and Git skips the copying.  This is true *even if you have modified a set of clean and/or smudge filters, or changed line-ending settings.*  In that particular case, where you want to force Git to re-clean the file on its way from work-tree to index, you must either trick Git into thinking that the work-tree file has changed:

```
touch <file>
```

or use the `--renormalize` option of `git add`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
git checkout HEAD -- <path>
git reset <path>
git add <path>
git commit
```