# What does `git show` with two nonoption arguments mean?

Tags: git

The manpage of `git show` says

```
git show [<options>] [<object>…]
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/7196615

```
git show some_commit_sha1 -- some_file.c
```

What does the command mean?

Are both `some_commit_sha1` and `some_file.c` `<object>` arguments?

Is it the same as

```
git show -- some_commit_sha1 some_file.c
```

Thanks.

Comment: You left out the part `| git apply -R`, which pipes the output of the displayed file from another commit to a patch.

Comment: At this moment, I am asking about `git show`

Comment: Nice.  You're taking that accepted answer out of context though.

Comment: I am   starting from pieces

Answer (score 2):

They're not both `<object>` arguments, and the documentation here is not very good.  However, `git show` is a user-oriented ("porcelain") command and using it to pipe to other Git commands is not generally good practice in the first place.

In this particular case, `git show <commit> -- <path>` winds up invoking the equivalent of `git log --no-walk --cc <commit> -- <path>`.  That is, it first runs the same code as `git log --no-walk` to produce the log message for that particular commit, formatted according to any format directives (none, so this defaults to `--pretty=medium`).  Then it produces a diff listing, even if the commit is a merge commit—by default, `git log` does not produce a diff listing for merge commits, hence the `--cc` option.

The various `git diff` commands—both the porcelain `git diff` itself, and the plumbing variants `git diff-tree`, `git diff-files`, and `git diff-index`—all allow you to specify particular pathnames or pathspecs.  Normally it's pretty clear whether something is a pathname (e.g., `README.txt`) or a commit-specifier (e.g., `master`).  There are ambiguous cases, though: what if you have a *file* named `master`?

To distinguish pathname / pathspec arguments from commit-specifiers in these ambiguous cases, these commands use the `--` convention defined by [the POSIX specifications for utility commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) (see Guideline 10 in particular).  That is:

```
git diff-tree master -- develop
```

tells `git diff-tree` that the *commit* you want is `master` and the *file* you care about is named `develop`, while:

```
git diff-tree develop -- master
```

tells `git diff-tree` that the *commit* is `develop` and the *file* is `master`, and:

```
git diff-tree develop master -- release
```

tells `git diff-tree` that the *two* commits are `develop` and `master` in that order, while the *file* is `release`.  Note that `git diff-tree` takes up to two `<tree-ish>` arguments: when given only one such argument, the implication is that the one argument is a commit specifier, and Git should diff the commit's parent(s) against the commit.

#### Conclusions

1. For reliability (to avoid getting tripped up by various `diff` configuration items, such as forced use of color sequences via `color.diff=always`), the command in the answer to which you linked really should read:

   ```
   git diff-tree -p <commit> -- <file> | git apply -R
   ```

   (the `-p` option to `diff-tree` turns on the `-r` option).
2. The `git show` documentation, particularly the synopsis line, is inadequate.  An improvement, not necessarily complete, would read:

   ```
   git show [<options>] [<object>...] [--] [<path>...]
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what `git show some_commit_sha1 -- some_file.c | git apply -R` does?

Comment: Since `git show` invokes the equivalent of `git log -p --cc` or `git diff-tree -p`, you get the changes from the parent(s) to the child. If there is more than one parent, this combined diff is useless as a patch, and the whole thing produces nothing useful, but if the commit has a single parent, the output from the diff is usable as a patch (see [the old `patch` utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix))), and `git apply` treats it as one. The `-R` flag tells `git apply` that the patch should be reversed, so it's reverse-applied: [continued next comment]

Comment: Where the patch says, e.g., "delete line 30, which used to consist of the following text: ...", Git will *insert* a line, consisting of that text. Where the patch says "insert line 45, consisting of the following text: ..." Git will *delete* line 45, provided it consists of that text. If there is sufficient context, the context is used to locate the places where lines should be removed or inserted, if they have moved.

Comment: Since the diff output shows what someone did *to* one specific file in that commit, the `git apply -R`, which reverse-applies that same patch, attempts to *undo* precisely the same thing, in the same file. That's not always possible, due to additional changes that may happened in since the commit in question, but if it *is* possible, that's what it achieves. Note that this is the same goal as `git revert` except that (1) we look only at one file, and (2) since `git revert` performs a three-way merge, it can succeed in cases where the patch will fail.