# How to create git alias that reverts a file from a specific commit

Tags: git

I wish to create a git alias that revert a file from a specific commit. e.g. I have the following commits:

```
aaaaaaaa(HEAD -> DEV-10685) fixup! chore(cloud connector): something c
bbbbbbbb chore(grpc): something b 
cccccccc refactor(agent communicator): something c
dddddddd (origin/master, origin/HEAD) fix(config): something d
```

by mistake, I commited a file `mistake.txt` that I didn't wish into  `cccccccc refactor(agent communicator): something c` along with valid changes.

I wish to create a git alias that of the form:
`git revert-file mistake.txt cccccccc`

to make things easier, I added here two **unrelated** git aliases, to demonstrate how to use function in git aliases

```
    rhm = reset --hard origin/master
    coom = ! "f() {  git fetch && git co origin/master; }; f"
```

I thought about something like:

- create a fixup that remove the file and rebase and squash it
- do a git rebase, edit the commit, and remove the file and finish the rebase

I didn't find an easy not risky way to do it, any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to create an alias for a one-time operation?

Comment: Since I'm sure that I'm not special, and if it happens to me every once in a while, probably will end up to be worth the time to have such an alias.
And everything that can be done with alias, might save human errors

Comment: Is this the workflow you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32528151/11082165

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now, you want the commit and the file to be a parameter. I was wondering why you would want to fix the same file in the same commit again after you have already fixed it.

Comment: @Brian61354270 yes. that's exactly the flow.

Comment: @OrYaacov you  can use `git checkout <error-commit-hash>~ <file>`. Command rolls back changes introduced to specified file by specified commit.

Comment: So, no need to have special command/alias here.

Comment: Do you want your alias A) to revert the file to what it was before cccccccc, even if the file was changed by other commits later? or B) to revert *only* the changes made in cccccccc and keep changes that were made in later commits (if any)?