# How to bring back removed file

Tags: git

In GIT working repo i removed couple of files with command rm -rf not git rm, When i try to pull/fetch from the server(bare repo) files are not visible. How do i bring those file back ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revert to a previous commit.  This will reset to last committed state:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Note...if you have other changes...be SURE you stash them first!

```
git stash
```

Here is an option taken from another post that might help you as well:

```
git checkout abcde file/to/restore
```

Where abcde is the commit #.  You can use:

```
git log
```

To get commit log.

[Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-do-i-reset-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Comment: if you can get the same effect without a hard reset, you should. it's a pretty dangerous command.

Comment: Thanks reset --hard HEAD brought back the file, Is reset --hard is dangerous, can you please explain more on that ?

Comment: Yea.  It reverts EVERYTHING under source control to the last committed state.  That means that if you changed files a, b, c and d in a commit, but you only wanted to recover a (which you accidently deleted), using reset --hard HEAD would bring you back to the state of each of those files (all 4 of them) before you made your last commit.  You're essentially "jumping back" one commit.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend `git checkout path/to/file.ext` if you only want to restore a single file (or do it a couple of times for a couple of files). Using `git reset --hard HEAD` will get all of your files back, but it will also wipe out any *other* changes you've made since your last commit that you might want to keep.

Comment: Thanks reset --hard HEAD brought back the file

Answer (score 0):

Always inspect the output of

```
git status
```

when in doubt. The output would have showed you how to get said filles back.

This would include instructions for deleted files and files/changes that got added to the index.

Comment: You are correct status shows how to get back, thanks for the info.