# Restore file from old commit in git

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have an old commit that I did a few weeks ago. I want to restore only a single file from that commit. What do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Answer (score 330, accepted):

```
git checkout 'master@{7 days ago}' -- path/to/file.txt
```

This will not alter HEAD, it will just overwrite the local file `path/to/file.txt`

See [man git-rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) for possible revision specifications there (of course a simple hash (like `dd9bacb`) will do nicely)

Don't forget to commit the change (after a review...)

Comment: Wow,  @heneryville and sehe , I actually thought '7 days ago' was meta for you would figure out what commit. ty!

Comment: Part 2 
When desiring to choose a particular commit, the above format does not work. Instead use what Urs showed below, 
git checkout commitShaNumber -- path/to/file.txt

per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-do-i-reset-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git

Comment: @AnneTheAgile in fact that's still exactly the same syntax, I just happened to give a "complex" example of a [`revision-specification`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) since that is what the OP asked :)

Comment: If your commit was used to delete the file you are trying to recover, just use `shacommit~1` (ex: `git checkout 0f4bbdcd~1 -- path/to/file.txt`) to get the commit immediately before.

Comment: I honestly thought the "7 days ago" bit was meant to be the commit hashcode.

Answer (score 121):

1. Check out the file from your old commit via `git checkout [Revision_Key] -- path/to/file`.
2. Add, commit, push as appropriate.

Comment: `git checkout` can handle single files (see answer by sehe), no need to copy and paste.

Comment: Are revision keys always the SHA1 for the commit?

Comment: They are, but usually the first 6 to 8 characters of the SHA1 are sufficient to identify the revision.

Comment: @IslandCow no, they can be sha1 but also branch, tag, or any other thing that points to a commit, e.g. `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, or any of those combined with `^`/`~`/`@`-style notation.

Comment: Works also with (non-empty) folders, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670745/how-to-restore-a-whole-directory-from-history-of-git-repository

Comment: You indicate that one is supposed to "add" the file afterwards. But that is incorrect. The file is not placed in the staging area. It's already added.

Answer (score 74):

All answers mention `git checkout <tree-ish> -- <pathspec>`. As of git v2.23.0 there's a new [git restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore/2.23.0) method which is supposed to assume part of what `git checkout` was responsible for. See highlights of changes on [github blog](https://github.blog/2019-08-16-highlights-from-git-2-23/).

The default behaviour of this command is to restore the state of a working tree with the content coming from the `source` parameter (which in your case will be a commit hash).

Assuming the commit hash is `abcdef` the command would look like this:

```
git restore --source=abcdef file_name
```

which (by default) puts it in working tree. If you want to put the change directly in index so it can be committed straight away:

```
git restore --source=abcdef --worktree --staged file_name
```

or with short option names:

```
git restore -sabcdef -W -S file_name
```

Comment: This should definitely now become the accepted answer, as it makes the others pretty much obsolete.

Answer (score 21):

I needed to restore a recent file committed into git.
So just to reiterate and give another perspective, you need to do this by running the following two steps:

1. `git log -3`
   This shows the three most recent commits. Read the comments and the author's name so you narrow down what exact version you want.
   Write down that long commit ID (e.g. `b6b94f2c19c456336d60b9409fb1e373036d3d71`) for the commit version you want.
2. `git checkout b6b94f2c19c456336d60b9409fb1e373036d3d71 -- myfile.java`
   Pass the commit ID AND the file name you want to restore. Make sure you have a space before and after the double hyphen.

There are many other ways to do it but this is the simplest one I can remember.

**NOTE:** If you are inside your project path/folder then is not necessary to type the full file's path in the checkout command.

Comment: Best comment ever. Because the one, which is the accepted answer, assumes that the file that has to be fetched is pushed upstream, however this command fetches/restores the file which only exists locally.

Comment: Just tried this in the root folder of my local git repo. I still needed to provide the relative path to the file. Just providing the -- [filename] on it's own didn't work.

Comment: @ot0 No, it doesn’t assume that. They are exactly the same answer.