# CSS to SCSS conversion

Tags: css, git, sass

I was working on a project and I accidentally removed the SCSS directory. It's been a while since my last commit, so `git reset` is an option, but a painful one.

I do however have all the sass cache files and the verbose, commented version of the CSS. Does anyone know of a way I can get all this back? Like a sort of SASS reversal.

Comment: A versioning system is useful exactly for this kind of issues... :) and no converter will be able to generate your original mixins or abstracted classes

Comment: Yeah, It's all controlled with git so I can roll back to an earlier version. But as I said, I've done a lot since my last commit and don't want to lose it ideally. Looks like this is my only option though :(

Comment: well, maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670745/how-to-restore-a-whole-directory-from-history-of-git-repository) could help you