# git-only command to restore a directory to a commit state

Tags: git, restore, git-checkout

I would like to restore a whole directory (recursively) from the history of my git repository (exactly like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9670745/2965109)).

I know that the right git command is:

```
git checkout [tree-ish] -- path/to/the/folder
```

But I have a problem: to restore an existing directory to the state of a commit, the content of the directory should be deleted first. In other case, existing files that didn't exist in the old commit won't be removed.
So, to obtain exactly what I want I have to do the following command:

```
rm -Rf path/to/the/folder
git checkout [tree-ish] -- path/to/the/folder/
```

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671161/2965109) and comments).

I'd like to know if there is a **git-only command** to achieve the same behaviour of the two commands above, in order to avoid making a `rm` manually.

EDIT:
I do not want to remove untracked files or clean after the checkout, I do not have them. I want to restore a folder exactly like it was some commit ago, removing added files, restoring removed files and so on.

Comment: You can do "`git clean -xdf`" after `git checkout`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-branch)

Comment: No, I don't do the rm to remove untracked file in my repo, I have to do it before the checkout in order to have a "real" checkout: I'd like to restore my folder in exactly the state of some commit ago. If I do not remove my folder before the checkout command, I'll be in a hybrid situation in which existing files that didn't exist in the old commit are still in the folder

Comment: @Rowandish I see now. So you want the effect of `git checkout <tree-ish>` (without any paths) but for a given path/subdirectory, right?

Comment: And what is the reason that you want to avoid the `rm`?

Comment: @Leon Exactly. I'd like to remove the rm beacause I access to my repo programmaticaly (LibGit2Sharp) and, If such git command exists, I can try to implement in LibGit2Sharp. If it is not possible I can do the rm without any kind of problems ;)

Comment: @Rowandish I couldn't find a git-only way of doing this.

Comment: @Leon Many thanks the same! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to avoid manually deleting files then you can create git-command-name file

> ```
>  #!/bin/bash
>  # main, path as argument...
>  rm -Rf path/to/the/folder 
>  git checkout [tree-ish] -- path/to/t
> ```

Put it into user/bin and git will recognised it as git command that you can call with

> git command-name [path/to/the/folder]

Comment: I couldn't accept it because it is not a git framework native command, but +1 for sure!