# How to restore files overwritten by git checkout

Tags: eclipse, git

I was working on my project (eclipse project with egit plugin) and I accidentally removed a file. I haven't committed the changes. I wanted to restore the file so I did:

```
git checkout commit src
```

Now my source files are replaced by those of my previous commit.

Is there any chance to restore the changes I have made? If yes how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624036/restore-file-from-old-commit-in-git/6624085
These answers may help you.

Comment: No it's not a duplicate of that question. I haven't commit my changes!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get your changes back. That is why you should be careful while checking out a file. Hard luck bro :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking out eclipse local history. Your file changes still should be there, even if you reverted them using git checkout.

Edit: You are out of luck. If you checked out over top of your changes, then you have lost them. Next time I would recommend trying `git stash` before checking out over your changes. That way you will be able to pop them off the stash.

Comment: No git override that option. I have only the files of last commit.