# How to recover a overwritten file on doing git pull

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have `admin.html file`. I modified it. I am working on `master`.
But before committing it, I did `git pull`.
There is `admin.html` file in BitBucket, and my (changed) `admin.html` file is overwritten by the `admin.html` file in BitBucket.

How can Irecover my changed `admin.html` file?

Comment: Did yuu add that file in the index (git add) before the git pull?

Comment: i am working on iteration branch.i tried to push by using git push origin iteration.it says git pull has to be done.i switched to master and made git add, git commit, and git pull.

Comment: But when you switched to master, was that admin.html file still there? (and still modified?)

Comment: yes.when i did git pull my changed file was overwritten by the file in bitbucket.

Comment: But it was committed first, *before* the git pull, right?

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on iteration branch. I tried to push by using `git push origin iteration`
>   It says `git pull` has to be done.
>   I switched to `master` and made `git add`, `git commit`, and `git pull`

Then [you can show](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338470/6309) or [restore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6624085/6309) an older version of that file (try `HEAD~`, or `git log -- admin.html` to find the right SHA1, [looking for its history](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History))