# How to recover local files removed by git pull?

Tags: git, github

I have local changes made, and I run "git pull".
My local files were overwritten by one remote commit. Is is possible for me to recover those uncommitted changes?

Comment: It might be possible if you have some other sort of backup, but git cannot recover anything except a commit. If your local changes were not committed (or stashed, which is a form of committing), they do not exist as far as git is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull` alone should not delete content without warning.

If the `autostash` option (mentioned by @VonC) is turned on on your machine, your changes may have been stashed away :

- run `git show stash` to view the content of the latest stash,
- if you changes do not show up in the latest stash, check :

  ```
   git stash list            # to have an overview of what is stored in the stash
   git stash show stash@{n}  # to view the content of a previous stash
  ```

If you find the content you are looking for in one of the stash entries, you can run :

```
git stash apply 
# or
git stash apply stash@{n}
```

to recover them.

Answer (score 0):

Local changes should (not yet add/committed) not be overwritten by a `git pull` (unless you did `git pull -f`)

I always prefer the [autostash feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

If your changes were added to the index before the pull, [you might check git fsck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109433/6309).
If they were actually committed, you [can restore them from git log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57676960/6309).