# isolate a file into a different branch and also retain its history

Tags: git, git-branch

I am working on a branch of git which has two files `A.c` and `B.c`.

I was creating patches which had changes made to both `A.c` and `B.c`

But Now I want all the changes made to `B.c` to be isolated from this branch and be created as a different branch, this branch should also have all the history of `B.c`.

This looks like an obvious use case as we may decide in the middle that `B.c` is a much critical file so needs a different branch, as some one else may need to work on it.

Comment: Branches in Git are usually repository-level - that is, you don't usually create a separate branch just to track history for a particular file.

Comment: I mean I want to create a separate branch that contains B.c and it should also have the history of the file

Comment: I don't understand why do you need that. Why would a “critical file” need its own branch?

Comment: So that someone else can take over its development and it has been added by mistake, no needs to be seperated and at the same time history needs to be retained

Comment: git reset HEAD^, unstage files corresponding to HEAD^,  x.c and y.c correspond to files of HEAD^, git reset HEAD x.c y.c (this will remove x.c and y.c from index of HEAD),git add A.c, git commit , here add a line Change ID: <your change ID that has A.c and B.c initially>, this will create a branch that has only A.c , Do similar things for creating branch which has only B.c (similar but not same steps)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already committed A.c and B.c, you can:

- create a new branch

  ```
  git checkout -b newBranch
  ```
- [reset `A.c` to a state where those modifications were not done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215731/6309)

  ```
  git checkout @~1 -- A.c
  git commit -m "Keep only B.c changes"
  ```

The end result is a new branch with only `B.c` patch, and the full history of `B.c`.