# Retrieving Core Data Managed Object Model from Git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, core-data, core-data-migration

I currently have v1.1 of an app in the App Store that uses Core Data.

I'm making simple changes to the Core Data schema by adding a few attributes to an existing entity for an upcoming release. Due to my naivety, I made the aforementioned changes on the existing Core Data managed object model from the release version.

While reading [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration) guide on lightweight migration, I came across this:

> It is therefore absolutely essential that you never make changes to the managed object model for a released version of an app. That is, if your app is already in the App Store, don’t change a single thing in that version of the managed object model.

This obviously concerned me, since it was what I had been doing while working on the upcoming version. I have been using Git and have consistently committed. **What would be the least painful way to restore the untouched managed object model from these Git revisions (assuming that some revision in Git does contain it).**

**Update/Edit** - It is not critical for me to migrate the current user's core data store as most of the data can be re-downloaded and I am using Core Data to create a smoother experience. **Will just using the currently modified Core Data managed object model cause any issues/crashes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just checkout the revision from Git that contains the model that you released with. Then take that model and copy it into your current revision. At that point you can create a new model version and be on your merry way.

If you do not want to mess with all of that you could just create a whole new model and define your app to use that new model, this would require you to re-download everything into that new model and a new persistent store. I would also write some code to remove the old model and persistent store file from their device if you went this route.

I don't think the first route should be too troublesome though.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to seach through your commit history, `git log` is one way, and locate the point you want to roll back to. Note the commit hash of the commit you want.

`git checkout commit-hash path/to/file`

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215731/620197) for full explanation.