# What is the best way to resolve Rails orphaned migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, migration, rails-migrations

I have been switching between branches in a project and each of them have different migrations... This is the scenario:

> $ rake db:migrate:status

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   ...
   up     20130307154128  Change columns in traffic capture
   up     20130311155109  Remove log settings
   up     20130311160901  Remove log alarm table
   up     20130320144219  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20130320161939  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20130320184628  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20130322004817  Add replicate to root settings
   up     20130403190042  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20130403195300  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20130403214000  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20130405164752  Fix ap hostnames
   up     20130410194222  ********** NO FILE **********
```

The problem is `rake db:rollback` don't work at all because of the missing files...

What should I do to be able to rollback again and get rid of the NO FILE messages?

Btw, `rake db:reset` or `rake db:drop` are not an option, I cannot lose data from other tables...

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem like this:

**(1)** Go to the branches that has the migration files and roll them back. This is not trivial when you have many branches which are will result in many conflicts if you try to merge them. So I use this commands to find out the branches of each orphan migration belongs to.

So, I need to find commit of the last time the migration was modified.

```
git log --all --reverse --stat | grep <LASTEST_ORPHAN_MIGRATION_ID> -C 10
```

I take the commit hash and determine which branch it belongs like this:

```
git branch --contains <COMMIT_HASH>
```

Then I can go back to that branch, do a rollback and repeat this process for all the missing files.

**(2)** Run migrations: checkout the branch you finally want to work on and run the migrations and you should be good to go.

**Troubleshooting**

I also ran in some cases where orphaned migrations where on deleted branches.

To solve this I created dummy migration files with the same migration_id of the missing files and roll them back. After that, I was able to delete they dummy migrations and have a clean migration status :)

Another alternative is deleting the missing files from the database directly (`rails dbconsole`):

```
delete from schema_migrations where version='<MIGRATION_ID>';
```

Comment: great answer. Do give us the easier, shorter, practical way first not last! =] I was getting all stressed out until, oh. goody.

Comment: Where do you type this?
`delete from schema_migrations where version='<MIGRATION_ID>';`

Comment: in your database console... you can access it typing:
`rails dbconsole`

Comment: @Adrian even shorter, you can type rails db ;)

Comment: If you have some problems with running `rails db` like I had, you can also do the same from rails console like: `sql = "delete from schema_migrations where version='<MIGRATION_ID>';"` and then `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`

Answer (score 63):

Migrations are stored in your database. If you want to remove the abandoned migrations, remove them from the db.

Example for Postgres:

1. Open psql:

   ```
   psql
   ```
2. Connect to your db:

   ```
   \c your_database
   ```
3. If you're curious, display schema_migrations:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM schema_migrations;
   ```
4. If you're curious, check if the abandoned migrations are present:

   ```
   SELECT version FROM schema_migrations WHERE version IN 
   ('20130320144219', '20130320161939', '20130320184628', '20130403190042',
    '20130403195300', '20130403214000', '20130410194222');
   ```
5. Delete them:

   ```
   DELETE FROM schema_migrations WHERE version IN (<version list as above>);
   ```

Now if you run `bundle exec rake db:migrate:status`, you'll see the orphaned migrations have been successfully removed.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome, and didn't ruin my staging data.

Answer (score 43):

Here is a rake version of the psql answer from @medik, which won't erase your db or do anything crazy:

1) Find your orphaned migration versions:

```
rails db:migrate:status
```

2) Note the versions of the missing migrations and head into the db console:

```
rails dbconsole
```

3) Now remove the versions from the migration table manually:

```
delete from schema_migrations where version='[version_number]';
```

Comment: This worked for me, Rails 6.0.0. Nice, clean, and simple.

Comment: note: remove the [ ] from version if there is only 1 version number.

Comment: Lovely, simply solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

Edit: **THE FOLLOWING WILL DROP YOUR DATABASE**

A simpler approach that has worked for me (note that this command will drop the database and all your data will be lost):

`rake db:migrate:reset`

..and then:

`rake db:migrate:status`

The orphan(s) should disappear.

Comment: **CAUTION: db:migrate:reset will drop the database, resulting in complete data loss!!**

Comment: PLEASE READ THE MESSAGE ABOVE THIS - Do not reset the database as you will lose all of your data.

Comment: “I don’t always blow away my database, but when I do, it's because I fail to read the SO comments first."

Comment: Nuking from orbit is guaranteed to eliminate orphans.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm haha! as well as any other children and men alive :/

Comment: What kind of sadistic person upvotes this as an answer? Do not do this to remove orphaned migrations.

Answer (score 5):

create new files with names like 
`20130320144219_migration_1` 
put some blank code into

```
class Migration1 < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def change; end 
end
```

and run command `rails db:migrate:down VERSION= 20130320144219` 
and at last - remove this files

Answer (score 4):

Here's a rake task I wrote for this purpose. It invokes the same method that the `db:migrate:status` uses under the hood, `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.migrations_status`

```
# lib/tasks/cleanup_migration_entries.rake

desc 'Removes schema_migration entries for removed migration files'
task 'db:migrate:cleanup': :environment do
  migration_context = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context
  versions_to_delete =
    migration_context.migrations_status
                     .filter_map { |_status, version, name| version if name.include?('NO FILE') }

  migration_context.schema_migration.delete_by(version: versions_to_delete)

  puts "Cleaned up #{versions_to_delete.size} orphaned migrations."
end
```

Comment: This is great if you don't care about the `down` effects of the missing migrations. Since my problem was a migration that had never been checked into version control in the first place, this solution helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I have created Migration for that.

```rb
class DeleteOrphanedMigrationFile < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    db_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    migration_context = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context
    removed_file_versions = migration_context.migrations_status.filter_map { |_status, version, name| version if name.include?('NO FILE') }

    removed_file_versions.each do |version|
      sql = "delete from schema_migrations where version='#{version}';"
      db_connection.execute(sql)
    end
  end

  def down; end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner for Rails console once you have the version numbers from failed `rake db:migrate` or NO FILE entries from `rake db:migrate:status`

```
 class SchemaMigration < ActiveRecord::Base; end; SchemaMigration.where(version: %i[the version numbers to delete]).delete_all
```

Which means, from terminal, you can

```
rails runner "class SchemaMigration < ActiveRecord::Base; end; SchemaMigration.where(version: %i[the version numbers to delete]).delete_all"
```

Though, at that point, it might be faster to use one of the direct database commands from previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Git, it should be relatively simple to grab these migrations and bring them into your current branch. If you have a specific commit you want a file from, you can use:

```
git checkout <commit hash> <file_name>
```

(Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-do-i-reset-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git))

Alternatively, you can check out from a specific branch HEAD:

```
git checkout <branch name> -- <file_name>
```

According to this [blog post](http://nicolasgallagher.com/git-checkout-specific-files-from-another-branch/)

Assuming these are, in fact, the versions of the migrations run on the database, you should be good to rollback.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The issue with this is that I'm working in a big project with a lot of branches and developers. So, I don't know which branch has the orphaned migration. I finally found the way (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could merge the two branches back into the master so that you have all migrations available.  If you really don't want those migrations there, but want to be able to roll back, you could edit the schema_migrations table in your database to remove the rows corresponding to the migrations for which you don't have files.  However, this will cause problems if you then switch to another branch with different migrations.

Comment: That's a good idea to merge the branches temporary and rollback until reach a good state. However, some of the branches didn't have a near ancestor commit, so they will have tons of conflicts during merging... I solved going to each of the branches containing the orphaned migrations rolling back and then come back to my branch again...

Answer (score 0):

If the migration files are truly missing (e.g. ran migration, forgot to roll back migration, then deleted migration file before commit), I was able to reproduce the missing migration as follows:

1. go back in git history to get a copy of the schema.rb file and save outside of git repo (`git log; git checkout xxxxxx; cp schema.rb ~/schema_old.rb, git checkout master)`.
2. run a diff on the two files, and copy the migration commands into a migration file that matches the missing migration ID (`diff schema.rb ~/schema_old.rb > migration_file.rb; vi migration_file.rb`)
3. Check your migration status and rollback (`rake db:migrate:status; rake db:rollback; rake db:migrate:status;`)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a gem written to solve this issue - [actual_db_schema](https://github.com/widefix/actual_db_schema)

The idea is to keep the run migrations inside the tmp folder. When you switch between branches it "remembers" all run migrations this way and rolls back for you automatically on `rails db:migrate` run (actually, on any rake task that causes db dump).