# How to remove old migration files that doesn't exist anymore on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

```
database: bird_app_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20231003031851  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20231006010235  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20231021170459  Create birds

rails db:rollback
bin/rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError: 

No migration with version number 20231006010235.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041790/what-is-the-best-way-to-resolve-rails-orphaned-migrations

Comment: https://dev.to/iamnan/fix-no-file-migrations-in-rails-7m6