# How to see previously committed version of file in Git

Tags: git

I have created a folder name `A` and have ran `git init` ( which initialized ).

Under it I created 2 files `a.txt` and `b.txt` and than ran `git add .` and then `git commit`.

Now those files were committed.

Now if I do modification to `a.txt` and save it, but want to checkout the original file ( saved during commit in local repository ) how can I do it ?

PS: I am doing it in CentOS server where GIT is installed, so it itself is a local repository and I want to fetch data from it.

Comment: what do you mean with *pull the original file*? Revert the changes introduced to a? Or watch the original version that is checked in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset/revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-do-i-reset-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the version of the file that was just commited:

```
git checkout -- <path-to-file>
```

Be aware that if  is a folder it will be applied recursively

If you just want to see the old file version:

```
git show COMMIT:<path-to-file>
```