# How to view local changes with git and revert them?

Tags: git

I cannot figure these out by myself (these are very easy to do with svn/rabbitvcs in Linux)

1. How to view local changes against central server (origin?) for one file? (graphically)
2. How to revert local changes for one file?

Also, when i do a pull, i get this error:

```
n $ git pull
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Application/powerbar.cpp
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

But when i do a `git diff` for the file it does not display anything.

**Edit:** Turns out that the file is a local file (powerbar.cpp), why does git want to overwrite my local file?

Edit:
When i do "git checkout myfile.cpp" the following is displayed: error: path 'myfile.cpp' is unmerged

When i do "git reset myfile.cpp' then what exactly happens? It does NOT revert my local changes.

Comment: What GUI client do you use?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `git status` to see changes in your local directory. It will show you what you haven't commited. If you have untracked files - that is also a change from git point of view.

Second, if you want to compare your local commits to remote server use

```
git diff origin/{your_branch}
```

Comment: I don't do local commits, i have the master branch and i commit to the central repository.

But still, how do i revert the local changes to get rid of merge conflicts? I know that when i delete the local files then git pull will not download them again for some reason.

Comment: you can do a "  git reset --hard  " to revert all your local changes if you are not doing any commits in your local , Be careful with this option though it deletes all the local untracked files from your repo and reversts changes.

Comment: @bupthebroker you can also use "git stash save" if you need these files, and after commiting get them with "git stash pop"

Comment: Can i do a git reset --hard for one file only?

What is the difference between git reset and git reset --hard, the help page seems to be in some form of cryptic language:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: @bupthebroker, here is how to reset one specific file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git

Comment: I just don't get it - that link seems to be for resetting to some specific revision.

How can such an easy task be so difficult.
I did a clone of the origin at some point in time, then i changed a few files locally. Now i want to revert my local changes in one file.

Comment: @bupthebroker it does not change anything: just find the last commit `abcde` you want your file to get back to (the commit you've cloned from origin) and use `git checkout abcde file/to/restore`

Comment: so i should write "git checkout origin myfile" ?

Comment: @bupthebroker, no, you should find the hash of the last commit in the origin repository, and use git checkout hash_of_that_commit file/to/restore

Comment: What does git checkout origin myfile do then?

Or what does git reset origin myfile do?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured out question no 2 out as well, therefore posting it as answer.

The source of my confusion lies in the inconsistent command syntax of git (explained by this great article: http://stevebennett.me/2012/02/24/10-things-i-hate-about-git/).

> To reset one file in your working directory to its committed state:
> git checkout file.txt
>
> To reset every file in your working directory to its committed state:
> git reset --hard

And a final comment if i may: It seems that git has a long way to go to reach the level on consistency, usability and simplicity of svn.