# What's the command to reset a file to a specific commit?

Tags: git

Using git, is there a command which I can reset a file to a specific commit in the commit log?

I know git checkout file can let me reset the file to HEAD, but how to reset to a specific commit version?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit

Comment: the post does not solve my problem I think. I need to know how to reset a specific file to its specific version?

Comment: Try this one so : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mind your terminology. With git "reset" refers to setting a ref (e.g. branch) to a new commit.
You want to put a file from some commit into your working copy. Exactly this is a "checkout".

You can checkout all files of a commit with

```
git checkout commit
```

or only part of the commit with

```
git checkout commit file
```

If you only want to "show" a file of some commit without changing your working copy you can also use

```
git show commit:file
```

Comment: Also, to avoid ambiguity between file names and ref names, you may need to `git checkout commit -- file`...