# How to remove line from commit and put back her to working directory?

Tags: git

I have data in the working directory for several future commits but i made mistake in some commit because it contains a line which must be in the future commit. So how can i delete that line from commit and return it to the working directory for next commit?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git?rq=1 ?

Comment: @KeillRandor:  Sounds like an interactive patch would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
git rebase -i target_commit_hash^
```

and edit the commit, unstage wanted line (`git reset HEAD -p`) and amend the commit. Then stage the file with this one line and save in a separate commit. After that continue the rebase.

Then do rebase again:

```
git rebase -i target_commit_hash^
```

and move the commit with your one line to the top of the tree.

Then:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

this will remove the temporary commit with your one line and make this line as unstaged.