# Remove long-gone name reveal

Tags: github, git-rewrite-history

I have a github repo where in my readme I put my friend's name by accident, which in a different commit he replaced with his username.

Now he's slightly concerned that anyone could look back in the git history and find his real name.

The commit just added that line with his name in it, then the file got jumbled a bit and then he committed to remove his name. And that was hundreds of commits ago. I just want to delete all references of his name.

How could I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Git+remove+sensitive+information+

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove sensitive line from earlier git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311368/remove-sensitive-line-from-earlier-git-commit) Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/62576