# Git : how to fix a file modification

Tags: git

My experience with git is limited. I am stuck with a problem where I made wrong changes to a couple of files (e.g foo.c and bar.c) and committed. After another commit I realized that my changes were bad. So, the wrong changes with these two files are in HEAD~1. The correct version of these files were checked in to HEAD~5 and HEAD~7 respectively.

What is the recommended way to remove the wrong edits? I tried this :

```
`git checkout SHA path_to_foo/foo.c`
```

But it does not actually modify foo.c so that I can create another commit with this.

Comment: Did you already push the commit?

Comment: @Tim : Yes, the commits are already pushed to the remote branch.

Comment: This post seems to give a pretty complete answer:
[reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git

Comment: @Ractoc: Thanks for sharing the link. It's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git revert <SHA>
```

where SHA points to the bad commit. As manual tells:

> ... revert the changes that the related    patches introduce, and
>   record some new commits that record them.

Comment: But I don't want to revert everything. I only want to fix these two files. There were other files that were modified as part of these commits.

Comment: What if there are a 1000 other files changed in that commit? You don't want to undo all of that just to 'fix' one file

Comment: then you have to revert changes by hand. Create a patch as git diff <SHA>~1 foo.c > revert.patch, patch -p 1 -R < revert.patch, and commit