# How to revert a single committed file that has been pushed in GIT?

Tags: git

I have done some research online, and I still could not figure out what is the best way to revert one single file that has been pushed to repository using GIT.

I have done Git Revert, but it reverts back the entire commit. So let's say if you have 2, 3 files in a commit, but you only want to revert back 1 file, that wouldn't really work well.

Any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: Very quick google search for `git revert a file` led to: [git: revert (reset) a single file](http://www.norbauer.com/rails-consulting/notes/git-revert-reset-a-single-file.html)

Comment: that is for Uncommitted changes. My changes have been committed and pushed

Comment: [`git revert a file to previous version`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reset or revert a file to a specific revision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-can-i-reset-or-revert-a-file-to-a-specific-revision)

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
git reset HEAD~1 -- file1.txt
git checkout -- file1.txt
git commit 
git push
```

#### How it works

[`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) brings the index entry of `file1.txt` to its state on `HEAD~1` (the previous commit, the one before the wrong update). It does not modify the working tree or the current branch.

[`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) makes the working tree version of `file1.txt` identical with the version from the index (this is the version we need, right?)

You cannot use [`git commit --amend`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) because the commit that you want to undo was already pushed to the remote repository. This is why you must create a new commit and push it.

Comment: minor comment - you can also just `git checkout HEAD~1 -- file1.txt` and shorten things by 1 step.

Answer (score 2):

First, revert the commit, but do not commit the revert: `git revert --no-commit <SHA>`. Then, unstage all the files that *would* be reverted with `git reset`. Then you can add just the files you want with `git add <file>`. Do a `git commit`, then clean up your working directory to match the index with `git checkout .`.