# Remove a file change from a git commit

Tags: git, github

I have two file changes in a git commit. I have sent a pull request and still it is not merged. I need to know the command of removing one file change from the pull request. I mean not to delete the file from the repository. But to to remove new local changes from my commit. Please advice me.Thanks

Comment: Does this work: git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file ??

Comment: did you already commit the changes? If you did, you'll have to [`revert`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git) them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do this:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

and then reset the unwanted file

```
git reset HEAD /path_to_the_file
```

and you can commit again.