# git: Revert back file from commit

Tags: git

I have committed a file with some changes.
 But now i don't want that changes so how should i revert back to original file
 keeping other files changes for next commit.

ex: 
 file1.c
 file2.c
 file3.c

I made changes in all three files and committed.
 Now i don't want file1.c changes, i want as of original. 
 i tried below but its not working.

`git checkout HEAD^ file1.c
  git checkout file1.c
  git commit --amend`

What else i am missing .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `reset` the file to the version you want and then commit it.

```
git reset HEAD^ file1.c
git add file1.c
git commit --amend
```

A second option would be to reset the entire tree to previous state and just don't commit the file

```
git reset HEAD^
git add file2.c git add file3.c
git commit
```

See much longer discussion here:
[Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Answer (score 0):

If there are only few changes, manually edit file1.c(back to state before commit) and commit that file again.

Comment: That i can do. But it in commit list it will show as changed file. That i dont want.