# After reverting a file to a previous revision git diff shows no differences?

Tags: git, diff, revert, git-checkout, git-revert

After [reverting a file to a previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git) in git

`git checkout abcdefg myfile`

`git diff myfile` <-- shows no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The revert pulls changes to staging so you have to use

`git diff --cached myfile`