# How to revert my remote git repository back to a certain commit?

Tags: git, github

I accidently ran:

```
git push origin +master
```

while trying to push a file to my Github repo. This command reset all the commit history and deleted a few files.

I was wondering if there is a way to reset my repo to a [certain commit having the hash `94b90dc1121ce477131fa60ffdc234591554b6c8`](https://github.com/AkHo1ic/EzSkype/tree/94b90dc1121ce477131fa60ffdc234591554b6c8).

Comment: I never knew about that `+` modifier.  I'd think that push using a refspec that would cause remote commits to become unreferenced would need a `-f` option before it would be applied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard 94b90dc1121ce477131fa60ffdc234591554b6c8
git push -f origin master
```

Here's an explanation of the commmands...

First, let's make sure you are on the master branch, so use the `checkout` command so your HEAD points to master.

What is `HEAD`?
It's basically the pointer that Git maintains to point to where you currently are in the Git tree.

In fact, most of these concepts like HEAD, and branches, are just pointers to different points in the tree.
Do a `gitk` from the command line to see the tree in a nice graphical format.

Next, let's `reset` your HEAD pointer to that exact commit that you had in your original question. This will basically make the files on your file-system match that commit.

Be careful will `reset --hard` though...if you have outstanding work, or commit's that are not-yet pushed to the server this may make them "unreachable" (think about that tree again)...if you "lose" commits from this command you can usually get them back by using the `reflog` though.

Finally, push the local state of your master branch to GitHub's master branch. The -f is there because you are re-writing the history of the branch, so you need to tell Git to "force" it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: This is a valid solution, yet it would be nice if you were to elaborate on what these command do in order to help understand the functionality of git.

Answer (score 3):

Jonathan's answer is correct. An alternative way to achieve the same is:

```
git push -f origin 94b90dc1121ce477131fa60ffdc234591554b6c8:master
```

Comment: Is this syntactic sugar for the Jonathan's answer, or does it work differently internally?

Comment: Sorry I didn't try out your method as Jonathan's already worked, thank you very much anyways!

Comment: @k0pernikus: It's syntactic sugar mostly. Jonathan first sets his local 'master' to the correct commit and then force pushes it to origin/master, while this force pushes the ref to origin/master directly without setting the local 'master' branch first.

Comment: So from a micro-optimization point of view this would be a tiny bit faster, as it doesn't change to local git repo. (How that is useful may be a different matter, as I guess one wants the local repo to reflect the origin anyway.) Wouldn't `git pull` using this approach try a merge commit?