# How to open GitHub Desktop commit files in Explorer?

Tags: github, github-desktop

Is there a way to open a particular file in GitHub Desktop in Explorer?

I know you can right click on a project and press 'Open in Explorer'.

What I want is to be able to quickly open these files:

[image]

Comment: If files aren't commited you cannot open them. However, if you have commited your files properly just right click in your project and select "Open in explorer"

Comment: For just one file, to send to an editor without overwriting the working tree, I would still use the command line: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34666232/6309