# Git revert from commit, revert from push

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm new to git.
I wonder why reverting changes is so complicated.
1. I want to know how to revert from a not pushed changed (only commit)

2.How to revert from a pushed change.

3.Is there any good interface for launching all these command from linux( non shell usage)

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git is quite powerful as we know it.
You can see what changes/differences there are between your local copy and repository by issuing this command:

```
git diff
```

If you have not yet staged or committed, you can replace your working directory with what git has by checking out into that file:

```
git checkout -- filename
```

where file name could be `index.html`

**Unstaging a file**

If you have accidentally added/stageg a file you didn't want to, you can unstage that file by issuing this command:

```
git reset HEAD filename
```

It essentially resets that file to the last commit stage.

**Undoing Commits**

This is a bit tricky and not as straightforward as the above two.
Changing previous commits can be deadly and break git workflow.

Bad News: If you want to change as far back as last two commits, well, you CAN't.

Good News: If you only want to change you last commit, well you CAN.

To add a new file to your last commit:

```
git add filename
git commit --amend -am "message goes here"
```

To change last commit message:

```
git commit --amend -m "new message goes here"
```

**Contradiction**

Although, I said you can't change anything other than your last commit, you can apply a fix.

One fix is to correct your mistake and commit again

The other fix is to revert the state of a file to before any previous commit. This fix needs to be done using a uniquely generated `SHA` key by Git for each commit. So what you want to do is grab the `SHA` key for the commit you want to revert back to. To get this key, you should run:

```
git log
```

You should get something like:

```
commit b83a5b0a0bbc3bd544cb06bdecb485a83da63008
Author: Username <exmaple@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 7 18:54:38 2016 +0100

        added limiting and offsetting results

commit 63a0e591ca7ff9538004afdbd6d07f7a3e5c417b
Author: Username <exmaple@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 7 14:12:34 2016 +0100

        removed authorization for login & logout
```

and just the commit key you want to revert to.

`63a0e591ca7ff9538004afdbd6d07f7a3e5c417b`
You don't have to copy everything. It is so uniquely generated that you could just grab the first 10 characters and run this command:

```
git checkout 63a0e591ca7ff9538004a -- filename
```

This command reverts that particular commit and put the file in your staging area. Like I showed before, if you want to remove this file from the staging area back into your working directory, you run:

```
git reset HEAD filename
```

also, to remove it from your working directory, run:

```
git checkout -- filename
```

Note: your last commit is the topmost listed log.

**Great News**

You can completely revert the changes of your last commit by using the `revert` command. What this command does is, it adds back deleted files/lines of code, change your modifications back to before it was added and committed. It essentially mirrors your commit.

Like seen before, you need tha `SHA` key to do this. Just grab the key like before and run:

```
git revert 63a0e591ca7ff9538004a
```

and git will show you what the commit message would look like, probably in a text editor of your choice. You could edit the commit message if you like. Just save and close the file and your working directory should be back to before.

Note: If your changes are great (files have moved, been renamed etc) you probably would have to merge branches after this command.

There is also the `reset` command that is quite powerful and must be used with caution. You can read more about it [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@awoyotoyin 
You should not "grab the SHA key for the commit you want to revert back to"

but instead, grab the SHA key for the commit you want to revert.

The docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert 
show the syntax as git revert ... ...

where ... is first described as:: Commits to revert.