# Git revert just some files in commit

Tags: git

I have few commits on github that I want to change. So in my previous commit I've changed some file/folders and I need to revert changes only for some of them. What is the best solution to make it.

Comment: Does this answer your question or hav I misunderstood?
[Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/215718/5358968)

Comment: so I have a commit that contains changes for one folder for a submodule. and I need to fix it, by reverting it to state before commit.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. Because it was marked as a duplicate, it can no longer be answered. This question was about reversing changes in a commit (a true revert), not just making a new commit with copies of files from an older one. See my [proposed answer as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50231389/1307074).

Answer (score 51):

You can use [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
git checkout HEAD~ -- file/to/revert
```

to stage a version of the file from the previous commit. Then just commit the changes and you're good to go! Of course, you can replace `HEAD~`, which references the previous commit, with a hash of a commit, a further-back ancestor, or any "tree-ish" object you wish.

Comment: thanks for answer, I've added comment below Steve answer.

Comment: seem git reset --soft HEAD^ twice return me to a previous state and I reset needed file to a previous commit state.

Comment: This merely discards changes to a file.

Answer (score 5):

> I have few commits on github that I want to change.
>     I need to revert changes only for some of them

---

Few options:

1. Checkout the desired files from the desired commit

   ```
   git checkout <commit> path/to/file
   ```

---

2. Interactive rebase

   ```
   // X is the number of commits you wish to edit
   git rebase -i HEAD~X
   ```

Once you squash your commits - choose the `e` for edit the commit.

[image]

---