# How to restore my scss file data

Tags: ruby, sass

I was make mistake in writing sass path to compilation code. 
My mistake is: 
`sass --watch css:scss` 
but i must write:
`sass --watch scss:css`
I'm lost all my scss file data :(

Comment: Do you use a version control system - `git` for example?

Comment: yes i using git

Comment: Did you consider to checkout the file from a former commit? Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/215731/2483313

Comment: Oh, it's work thanks :)

Comment: but it's restore my data to not current point, i now want to use sass-cache folder to back to current point