# How can I revert a file in a commit or pull request to the state it was in when I created the branch?

Tags: xcode, git, github

Hypothetical:

I'm working on a project and let's say I create a branch `table-settings` off of `master`. I commit changes to three files:

- `plate.swift`
- `bowl.swift`
- `fork.swift`

Someone comments on my pull request and says, "We don't need those changes to `plate.swift` right now.

Either on github, the command line, or a source control desktop app, *is there a way that I can revert all changes to a single file in a commit or pull request, back to the state it was in when I created the branch?*

What makes this different from "How do I revert a file to the previous commit", is that I'm wondering if I can revert a file that's been edited and committed multiple times, to the state that it was at when I created the feature branch it's on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Comment: Yes, but if they are off in a branch, who cares?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth So after reading the other answer, I can just git log, and get the hash of the commit on `master` before I started committing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make it to a state that's in master then do following from your branch

```
git checkout master -- /path/to/plate.swift
```

above command will make it to a state, that's in master. Then commit and push normally. e.g.

```
git commit -m 'reverting not-required changes'
git push;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The duplicate link in the comments basically has you covered, but in this situation I might be inclined to do the following:

```
git checkout HEAD~1 path/to/plate.swift
```

This will reset `plate.swift` to the version one revision prior, when you created the branch.  Then you can amend the commit via

```
git commit --amend
```

Now your commit will contain all the previous changes minus the changes to `plate.swift`, which file will appear unchanged.  You would then have to force push using this:

```
git push --force origin table-settings
```

The reason the force push is needed is because we have rewritten the last commit in the branch.  But this approach is possibly nice for the reviewers, who will see a feature branch which looks very similar as when they commented.

If your feature branch has already been checked out by reviewers, then a safer option would be to just do a normal commit:

```
git commit -m 'reverted Plate.swift'
```

But I have found that amending can be useful when you end up having to make a number of tweaks to a pull request but you don't want to uglify your branch's history with many commits.