# How can I remove a file that is about to be pushed?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I somehow have a file that I didn't commit (at least recently), I can't seem to remove it using:

```
git rm -r --cached PathToFile
```

When I check what will be pushed when I push the file I removed is still listed using:

```
git diff --stat --cached origin/master
```

Does anybody know what's wrong?

The issue is I can't commit the file because it's over 100MB, it's currently on my .gitingore, but I guess the change to gitignore was made after the file was commited somehow. I don't want LFS, I already maxed it for no reason.

Comment: The file is part of your history already, at least this is my guess.  If so, you need to remove it from history in addition to doing `git rm --cached`.

Comment: When you say history, do you mean remove it completely from the repo?

Comment: Not necessarily the repo, just your branch (at least for starters)

Comment: Okay thanks, guess I'll find out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Once it is commited, it is added to the chain. So try hard resetting repo or file to the previous version. Refer. [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git). Else Use this docs to remove the file from repo history https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/

Comment: Hard resetting would wipe everything out, cause problems for others using the branch, and is probably not an option the OP would want to use here.

Comment: Hard reset will be useful when the only  thing  he did was adding a new file.