# How to revert specified file to before version using git?

Tags: git, github

How to revert specified file to before version? for examples:( the next line is latter time )

```
commitIDa create main.go and other operations
commitIDb modify main.go to content1 and other operations
...... (may be a lot of logs)
commitIDc modify main.go to content2 and other operations
commitIDd ??????(my demand is following:)
```

Now,I want the file main.go content to revert commitIDb ,and  **its log**  is only :

```
commitIDa
commitIDb
```

except for file main.go, other operations files may  have the logs following:

```
commitIDa
commitIDb
...
commitIDc
commitIDd
```

In other words，I want to delete main.go log information from (...) and commitIDc

Then I can git push to the remote origin

**[reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git) could not works.And my question is different frrom it. Because it will commit new commitID, and its content is same with the before one.**

**The core difference of my question is :    main.go  logs is only commitIDa commitIDb ,no new commitID to be commited. In the other words, it delete about main.go logs from the logs which is after commitIDb**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Comment: What do you mean by "This did not work?" what have you tried and what did you get?

Comment: From my test, the file main.go still have ... and commitIDc logs，I hope its logs only commitIDa
commitIDb

Comment: git checkout HEAD~2 -- main.go  ， git log ,      It still as usual

Comment: You cannot change the history of one file only. A commit includes all the files of the project (that were tracked when the commit was created). In order to remove some commits from the history of a file you have to rewrite the history and change those commits to not change the file. It is not difficult but if the current history has already been pushed, it is not recommended to change the history; it will confuse the other people that work on the project.

Comment: You made a really good point. But does the git support this operation now? Could you provide the solution ? Now I wanna changed my created branch about this point.

Comment: read the git book, and especially the parts about git rebase.

Comment: rebase could not help me, it will affect other files' logs

Comment: @Thibault D,  Dear !my question really different from  [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Comment: You cannot do what you are asking for