# How do you revert a file in Git only?

Tags: git

I updated files and committed them, e.g.

```
git add *lots of files*
git add b.txt
git commit -m 'Update files'
```

Now I realize I actually want to make the changes to `b.txt` in a different commit. I want to remove the changes to `b.txt` from my commit, but I want to keep the changes in the filesystem. If `b.txt` were a new file, I could do this with

```
git rm --cached b.txt
```

But this doesn't work for reverting `b.txt` to its previous state in the staging area.

Basically, I want to check out directly into the staging area without modifying my local files. Is there a way to accomplish this with a single command in Git?

This question is not a duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718) because that asker wants to change the working tree, but here I don't want to change the working tree.

Comment: Hint: `git reset --mixed`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Comment: codemonkeh: That question says how to reset both the index and the working tree for a specific file/version. I'm asking how to update the index for a specific file/version *without* overwriting the working tree.

Dai: `reset --mixed` is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! If you create an answer I'll accept it

Comment: In this case I used `git reset --mixed HEAD^ -- b.txt`

Comment: Actually `--mixed` isn't required because it's the default mode for `git reset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, I want to check out directly into the staging area without modifying my local files. Is there a way to accomplish this with a single command in Git?

You can undo changes on a single file or directory from commit, but retain them in the unstaged state.

`git reset commit-id <file>`

Answer (score 0):

You can git checkout a specific file for a specific commit. For example, if the commit a12345 holds the changes of b.txt that you would like to revert to, you can run:

`git checkout a12345 -- path/to/file/to/restore/b.txt`

See the [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) command for more info.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it to create a new branch on your actual commit and then reset your master back to the previews state. Then your commit is in the new branch.

```
git branch new_branch
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git checkout new_branch
```

something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming rewriting the history is fine for you. First, undo the commit by using `reset --soft`, which will keep the files added. Then unstage your file, and finally commit again:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
git reset -- b.txt
git commit -C HEAD@{1}
```

(Committing with `-C HEAD@{1}` to keep the old commit message.)