# Git command to reset to previous commit without losing commits

Tags: git

Case:

The commit history is:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

I hope to reset the current work dir to B on current branch with history:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

The result of the tree is same to `B`, which means

```
git diff B..E --name-only
```

should returns empty list.

A stupid way is:

```
# we assume current work directory is `tree`, and branch is `master`
# and work directory HEAD at `D`

# reset HEAD to D
cd tree
git checkout -f D

# create a copy work directory
cd ..
rm -rf copy
cp -r tree copy

# clean old work directory
rm -rf tree
mkdir tree
cp -r copy/.git tree/.git

# reset copy directory to revision `B`
cd copy
git checkout -f B

# copy tree from copy directory to tree
rm -rf .git
cp -r ./.* ./* ../tree

# commit changes, current revision is we wanted `E`
git add .
git ci -m 'revert to commit B'
```

Is there a simplified way to do this?

Comment: This is just an all-files variant of https://stackoverflow.com/q/215718/1256452, not sure if I should close as duplicate though.

Answer (score 0):

Just revert the intermediate commits:

```
git revert D C
```

You might need to squash the resulting commits then.

Comment: This leads to two problems: the first is it will create multiple commits, the result will be `A -> B -> C -> D -> D' -> C'`, and the second is that may be meat a merge commit or conflicts, it could not be handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

checkout files in commit B

```
git checkout B -- .
```

you can see the changes B and D

```
git diff HEAD
```

then commit it