# Revert only a single file of a pushed commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-reset, git-revert

Below is the the pushed commits history.

```
Commit      Changed Files
Commit 1|  (File a, File b, File c)
Commit 2|  (File a, File b, File c)
Commit 3|  (File a, File b, File c)
Commit 4|  (File a, File b, File c)
Commit 5|  (File a, File b, File c)
```

I want to revert the changes happened to  **File b** of **Commit 3**.

***But... I want to keep the changes that happened to this file in Commits 4 and 5.***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Comment: @Andreas The mentioned one is, just reverting to an earlier version.

Comment: @AkiT the [top answer to the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215731/327074) mentioned by Andreas describes what you want - where you checkout a file for a specific historic commit over the current file

Comment: @icc97 How would that help to keep “the changes happened to this file in commit 4 and 5.”?

Comment: @Melebius good question - my comment might be incorrect. There is detail in the question that I missed from the title.

Comment: @Andreas the sentence at the end makes this question **not** a duplicate. This is only reverting one commit from a bunch of commits. Your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git) would revert all commits going back to the specified commit.

Comment: This seems like a reverse `cherry-pick`

Comment: @Melebius Note as per the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53544830/327074) - the question was edited to add in the last sentence *You edited your question, though, to ask for something rather different.*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Git, each commit saves a *snapshot*—that is, the state of *every* file—rather than a set of changes.

However, every commit—well, *almost* every commit—also has a *parent* (previous) commit.  If you ask Git, e.g., *what happened in commit `a123456`?*, what Git does is find the *parent* of `a123456`, extract *that* snapshot, then extract `a123456` itself, and then compare the two.  Whatever is *different* in `a123456`, that's what Git will tell you.

Since each commit is a complete snapshot, it's easy to revert *to* a particular version of a particular file in a particular commit.  You just tell Git: *Get me file `b.ext` from commit `a123456`*, for instance, and now you have the version of file *`b.ext`* from commit `a123456`.  That's what you seemed to be asking, and hence what the linked question and current answer (as of when I am typing this) provide.  You edited your question, though, to ask for something rather different.

#### A bit more background

I now have to guess at the actual hash IDs for each of your five commits.  (Every commit has a unique hash ID.  The hash ID—the big ugly string of letters and numbers—is the "true name" of the commit.  This hash ID never changes; using it always gets you *that* commit, as long as that commit exists.)  But they're big ugly strings of letters and numbers, so instead of guessing, say, `8858448bb49332d353febc078ce4a3abcc962efe`, I'll just call your "commit 1" `D`, your "commit 2" `E`, and so on.

Since most commits have a single parent, which lets Git hop backwards from the newer commits to the older ones, let's arrange them in a line with these backwards arrows:

```
... <-D <-E <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

A *branch name* like `master` really just holds the hash ID of the *latest* commit on that branch.  We say that the name *points to* the commit, because it has the hash ID that lets Git retrieve the commit.  So `master` points to `H`.  But `H` has the hash ID of `G`, so `H` points to its parent `G`; `G` has the hash ID of `F`; and so on.  That's how Git manages to show you commit `H` in the first place: you ask Git *Which commit is `master`?* and it says `H`.  You ask Git to show you `H` and Git extracts *both `G` and `H`* and compares them, and tells you what changed in `H`.

#### What you've asked for

> I want to revert the changes happened to File b of Commit 3 [`F`]. But I want the changes [that] happened to this file in commit 4 and 5 [`G` and `H`].

Note that this version of the file *probably does not appear in any commit*.  If we take the file as it appears in commit `E` (your Commit 2), we get one without the changes from `F`, but it does not have the changes from `G` and `H` added to it.  If we go ahead and *do* add the changes from `G` to it, that's probably not the same as what's *in* `G`; and if we add the changes from `H` to it after that, that's probably not the same as what's *in* `H`.

Obviously, then, this is going to be a little harder.

#### Git provides `git revert` to do this, but it does too much

The `git revert` command is designed to do this sort of thing, but it does it on a *commit-wide basis*.  What `git revert` does, in effect, is to figure out what changed in some commit, and then (try to) *undo* just *those changes*.

Here is a fairly good way to think of `git revert`:  It turns the commit—the snapshot—into a set of changes, just like every other Git command that views a commit, by comparing the commit to its parent.  So for commit `F`, it would compare it to commit `E`, finding the changes to files `a`, `b`, and `c`.  Then—here's the first tricky bit—it *reverse-applies those changes* to your *current* commit.  That is, since you're actually on commit `H`, `git revert` can take whatever is in all three files—`a`, `b`, and `c`—and (try to) *undo* exactly what got done *to* them in commit `E`.

(It's actually a bit more complicated, because this "undo the changes" idea also takes into account the *other* changes made since commit `F`, using Git's three-way merge machinery.)

Having reverse-applied all the changes from some particular commit, `git revert` now makes a *new* commit.  So if you did a `git revert <hash of F>` you'd get a *new* commit, which we can call `I`:

```
...--D--E--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

in which `F`'s changes to all three files are backed out, producing three versions that probably aren't in *any* of the earlier commits.  But that's too much: you only wanted `F`'s changes to `b` backed-out.

#### The solution is thus to do a little less, or do too much and then fix it up

We already described the `git revert` action as: *find the changes, then reverse-apply the same changes*.  We can do this manually, on our own, using a few Git commands.  Let's start with `git diff` or the short-hand version, `git show`: both of these turn *snapshots* into changes.

- With `git diff`, we point Git to the parent `E` and the child `F` and ask Git: *What's the difference between these two?*  Git extracts the files, compares them, and shows us what changed.
- With `git show`, we point Git to commit `F`; Git finds the parent `E` on its own, and extracts the files and compares them and shows us what changed (prefixed with the log message).  That is, `git show commit` amounts to `git log` (for just that one commit) followed by `git diff` (from that commit's parent, to that commit).

The changes that Git will show are, in essence, *instructions:* they tell us that if we start with the files that are in `E`, remove some lines, and insert some other lines, we'll get the files that are in `F`.  So we just need to *reverse* the diff, which is easy enough.  In fact, we have two ways to do this: we can swap the hash IDs with `git diff`, or we can use the `-R` flag to either `git diff` or `git show`.  Then we'll get instructions that say, in essence: *If you start with the files from `F`, and apply these instructions, you'll get the files from `E`.*

Of course, these instructions will tell us to make changes to *all three* files, `a`, `b`, and `c`.  But now we can *strip away* the instructions for two of the three files, leaving only the instructions we *want*.

There are, again, multiple ways to do this.  The obvious one is to save all the instructions in a file, and then edit the file:

`git show -R hash-of-F > /tmp/instructions`

(and then edit `/tmp/instructions`).  There's an even easier way, though, which is to tell Git: *only bother showing instructions for particular files*.  The file we care about is `b`, so:

`git show -R hash-of-F -- b > /tmp/instructions`

If you check the instructions file, it should now describe how to take what's in `F` and un-change `b` to make it look like what's in `E` instead.

Now we just need to have Git apply these instructions, except that instead of the file from commit `F`, we'll use the file from the *current* commit `H`, which is already sitting in our work-tree ready to be patched.  The Git command that applies a patch—a set of instructions on how to change some set of files—is `git apply`, so:

```
git apply < /tmp/instructions
```

should do the trick.  (Note, though, that this will *fail* if the instructions say to change lines in `b` that were subsequently changed by commits `G` or `H`.  This is where `git revert` is smarter, because it can do that whole "merge" thing.)

Once the instructions are successfully applied, we can look over the file, make sure it looks right, and use `git add` and `git commit` as usual.

(Side note: you can do this all in one pass using:

`git show -R hash -- b | git apply`

And, `git apply` has its own `-R` or `--reverse` flag as well, so you can spell this:

`git show hash -- b | git apply -R`

which does the same thing.  There are additional `git apply` flags, including `-3` / `--3way` that will let it do fancier things, much like `git revert` does.)

#### The "do too much, then back some of it out" approach

The other relatively easy way to deal with this is to let `git revert` do all of its work.  This will, of course, back out the changes to the *other* files, that you didn't want backed-out.  But we showed at the top how ridiculously easy it is to get *any* file from *any* commit.  Suppose, then, that we let Git undo *all* the changes in `F`:

`git revert hash-of-F`

which makes new commit `I` that backs out *everything* in `F`:

```
...--D--E--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

It's now trivial to `git checkout` the two files `a` and `c` *from* commit `H`:

`git checkout hash-of-H -- a c`

and then make a new commit `J`:

```
...--D--E--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master
```

The file `b` in both `I` and `J` is the way we want it, and the files `a` and `c` in `J` are the way we want them—they match the files `a` and `c` in `H`—so we're now pretty much done, except for the annoying extra commit `I`.

We can get rid of `I` in several ways:

- Use `git commit --amend` when making `J`: this pushes `I` out of the way, by making commit `J` use commit `H` as `J`'s parent.  Commit `I` still exists, it's just abandoned.  Eventually (after roughly a month) it expires and really goes away.

  The commit graph, if we do this, looks like this:

  ```
                     I   [abandoned]
                    /
  ...--D--E--F--G--H--J   <-- master
  ```
- Or, `git revert` has a `-n` flag that tells Git: *Do the revert, but don't commit the result.*  (This also enables doing a revert with a dirty index and/or work-tree, though if you make sure you start with a clean checkout of commit `H` you don't need to worry about what this means.)  Here we'll start with `H`, revert `F`, then tell Git *get files `a` and `c` back from commit `H`*:

  `git revert -n hash-of-F`
  `git checkout HEAD -- a c`
  `git commit`

  Since we're on commit `H` when we do this, we can use the name `HEAD` to refer to the copies of `a` and `c` that are in commit `H`.

(Git being Git, there are a half dozen additional ways to do this; I'm just using the ones that we're illustrating in general here.)

Comment: Thank you, I have the exact same issue, and your answer is exactly what I need. On question though : why do you get rid of I ? if J is the HEAD, wouldn't it mean that the actual content is what we want ? Is getting rid of I absolutely necessary ?