# git revert issue with merge strategy (theirs)

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I want to revert to a previous commit of the branch with taking all the changes in that commit and nothing from the current one.

I have setup my test directory as below:

```
mkdir test_dir
cd test_dir

git init .

touch a_file

git add a_file
git commit -am "file added."
# say commit id 0_afile

echo "1 line" >> a_file
git commit -am "1 line"
# say commit id 1_afile

echo "2 line" >> a_file
git commit -am "2 line"
# say commit id 2_afile

echo "3 line" >> a_file
git commit -am "3 line"
# say commit id 3_afile

echo "4 line" >> a_file
git commit -am "4 line"
# say commit id 4_afile
```

When I run `git revert --no-edit -X theirs 2_afile`. I'm expecting content of `0_afile`, `1_afile` and `2_afile` commits but the result doesn't contains content of `2_afile`. Could someone points out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems somewhat self-contradictory to me:

> I want to revert **to** a previous commit of the branch ...

(boldface is mine; note that this is easy; see, e.g., [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/215718/1256452) though it's for some specific file or files)

> ... with taking all the **changes** in that commit and nothing from the current one.

Commits aren't *changes*, commits are *states*.

To use a simple example, suppose I tell you that it is currently 68˚F (20˚C) outside, on a Friday.  That's a *state*.  If I ask you what the change is from yesterday's temperature, can you tell me?  What else do you need to know first?

If the temperature goes up 9˚F (5˚C), that's a *change*.  If I tell you it went up that much on Monday vs Sunday, what temperature *was* it on Sunday?  What else do I need to tell you first?

---

In Git, each commit is a complete snapshot of *all* the files, in whatever state they have at the time you make the commit.  To get *changes* from a commit, it's necessary to *compare* that commit to some other commit.  The obvious "other" commit is the immediately-preceding commit, i.e., the commit's *parent*.  If a commit has only one parent, Git can do this automatically: it extracts the previous commit's files (a state), and the given commit's files (another state), and then *subtracts them* to produce the set of changes.

If you want the content of one file from a previous commit, that's easy; see the linked question, and this is a duplicate.  What `git revert` does is quite different: it turns a commit—a state—into a change, and then tries to apply that same change to the *current* state.  See my recent answer to [Revert only a single file of a pushed commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53533093/1256452), for instance.