# How can I revert this command "git status --porcelain | grep '^??' | cut -c4- >> .gitignore"?

Tags: git, github

Intially to ignore the untracked files permanently I ran a

```
git status --porcelain | grep '^??' | cut -c4- >> .gitignore
```

command. Now when I add a new file in my code, it is not showing in git status.

Comment: You can just manually edit the `.gitignore` file, or you can revert it back to a previous version using the commit history. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git for the specifics of how to do that

Comment: `git status` reports directories, not their files, if nothing in that directory is already tracked. Most likely, you are ignoring an entire directory, and your new files are in that directory.

Answer (score 4):

You have overwritten your `.gitignore` with the data of your changed files. A `git status --porcelain` output has no meaning in the syntax of the `.gitignore`.

You need to recover your `.gitignore`. The simplest way is - assuming you had no local, not committed change to it - is

```
git checkout -- .gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add your files anyway, you have several options :

- use `git add -f file` to disregard `.gitignore` and add the file anyway
- edit the `.gitignore` file to remove the lines which should not be ignored

If you want to undo the changes that were applied to `.gitignore` : just edit the file (with a text editor).

`[anycommand] >> .gitignore` just adds the output of `[anycommand]` at the end of the file ;
you should be able to spot the section with all the files listed by :

```
git status --porcelain | grep '^??' | cut -c4-
```

and just delete that section.

---

You should probably modify your `.gitignore` file anyway, it is not very conventional to ignore a long list of specific files.

- if you *really* want to ignore every untracked file (current and future), set your `.gitignore` to :

  ```
  # ignore everything
  *
  ```

  you can still add new files using `git add -f`
- if you want to ignore specific folders, just name those folders :

  ```
  # ignore the "tmp/" and "build/" directories :
  tmp/
  build/
  ```

For an extensive documentation : see `git help ignore`

Comment: The first option doesn't really make a lot of sense if the OP wants to "revert" the command given. Editing `.gitignore` to remove the lines added is a reasonable plan though.