# How to pull some files from an old commit to the current master

Tags: git

I have a repository that belongs only to me but allows me to manage a project across multiple machines with versioning.  Somehow, at some point I committed in such a way that some important includes were deleted, but I did not notice until I needed them today.  So I am trying to figure out how to take the versions of those files from the last commit where I know they are correct and pull them into the current master.  There are a couple of questions on here that seem like they should answer this, but the answers seem to be describing something else.

I can check out from the correct commit and I read about rebasing, but I am hesitant to do anything without asking those with more experience.

Comment: `git show ${commithash}:${file} > oldfile` to save the the file from the old commit in a file named "oldfile". I wouldn't rebase or you have to force push. Unless you haven't pushed any changed until the evil commit or you are the only developer.

Comment: Thanks!  What if it is a few directories?  Does this work to rebuilt a whole directory that is not there anymore?

Comment: @Cubimon reset or checkout can also be used to accomplish this. Maybe cat-file if you get the tree and blob

Comment: @Cubimon This should be an answer.

Comment: @KirkS. Git only deals in files, not in folders. If the last file in a directory is deleted, the directory will cease to exist in git. Vice versa as soon as you create a file in a new (non-tracked) subdirectory, git will know this directory as part of its scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reset or revert a file to a specific revision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-can-i-reset-or-revert-a-file-to-a-specific-revision)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+file+from+old+commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git checkout` to put back the deleted files into your working directory.

Assuming you already know which commit deleted the files, you can say:

```
git checkout <commit-ish>^ -- <deleted-path>
```

where:

- `commit-ish` is [a reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefcommit-ishacommit-ishalsocommittish) to the commit in question
- `^` references that commit's parent
- `deleted-path` is the path of the file or directory that you want to restore

For example, assuming `a12b34` is the SHA-1 of the commit that deleted the `foo` directory, you would say:

```
git checkout a12b34^ -- path/to/foo
```

In short, this commands tells Git to get the files in the specified path *as they were* before the commit that deleted them, and put them back in the working directory.

Comment: Thanks.  When you say ^ references the parent, does that mean I need to replace it with sometime?  I think I did not understand that part.

Also, once I have checked out these directories, does that mean I can then commit them to the current master?

Comment: @KirkS. `^` is a reference to a commit's parent. You want to get the files _before_ they were deleted, so assuming `123abc` is the SHA-1 of the commit that deleted the files, you want to get them from the commit that came before it (aka. the parent) so you say `123abc^`. Yes, after you've checked out the files, you can commit them again to the current branch.

Comment: Thanks.  This was exactly what was needed!

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --summary --diff-filter=D
```

Let's say you find out the exact commit hash as `abcde12345` where this important file was deleted.

```
git checkout $commit~1 path/to/file.ext
```

Where $commit is the value of the commit you've found `abcde12345`