# Accidental directory deletion - Git

Tags: git, github

I accidentally deleted all of my files whilst trying to push them to GitHub in what would have been the first commit (I have no idea how I managed this).

I have no local backup and no remote backup but in my GitLens VSCode extension the files are still there and viewable: 
[image]

How can I revert my current file tree back to what's being shown in GitLens?

Comment: what do you see when you try `git log` ? I don't know GitLens that much, but if it is still able to see your code, it means that your code must be stored in some local commit

Comment: @mr.mams I've just checked the repository on GitHub and the files are all there in a previous commit. Any idea how I can revert to that commit?

Comment: You can check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-can-i-reset-or-revert-a-file-to-a-specific-revision?rq=1

Comment: @mr.mams If I use git checkout I get this message: ```error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        public/css/app.css
        public/js/app.js
        public/mix-manifest.json
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting```

Comment: Seems like you have local changes that are not committed yet. You can use `git stash` to keep these changes aside. Then you can try again to use `git checkout`

Comment: @mr.mams I now have that commit back but for some reason my node_modules folder and vendor folder are in a separate commit. Could I merge the two together some how?

Comment: node_moduls and vendor folder should not be uploaded to git . For using them package.json and composer.json are engough

Answer (score 2):

Since you can see in gitlens, it means your files are present in previous commit.

You can do checkout to get it back as @mr.mams mentioned.
You can also undo your commit, check [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git/927386#927386)

To merge two commits you need to squash your commits. Check [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to recover all the files aside from vendor and node_modules, ran `npm install` and `composer install` and this fixed that issue. Still not sure how this happened though. Will have to brush up on my git skills methinks.