# Fetch a specific file from a Git Repo into a fork

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have forked a git repo and then later deleted a file in the fork and committed changes to the fork. Is there a way to just get this one file back from the original repo? Is this possible without having to revert my delete commit in the fork?

Comment: Can't you just clone the original repo and copy the file into your fork?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+restore+file+from+old+commit

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-can-i-reset-or-revert-a-file-to-a-specific-revision

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 I can but I was curious if there is a git friendly cleaner way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly, you can get the file back even from *your* repo. Remember, your clone contains a copy of the entire history, meaning every commit — and every commit contains all your files at the time of the commit, and no commit is ever lost. You just need to know the SHA of the last commit before the commit that deleted it. Then `git checkout <SHA-of-commit> -- <path-of-file>`.