# I had commit 10 files at a time in git but now how can I revert only 2 of them

Tags: git, github

I had pushed those 10 commit files in git and pushed them in master branch on github but now I have to revert 2 file of them back to the previous version.As far as I know if I revert back with commit Id all 10 files will get reverted but I don't want that. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Yash. I'm afraid this is 2) not technically a question and 2) it's also not detailed enough for anyone to give a useful answer. Can you elaborate? (before probable downvotes start to rain down)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-can-i-reset-or-revert-a-file-to-a-specific-revision

Comment: Slightly better now, but it's probably a duplicate, see above. Thanks for the quick update.

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
git revert <your-commit-id>
git reset --mixed HEAD~
git add <files-to-be-reverted>
git commit -m 'revert the two files'
git reset --hard
```

explanation:

`git revert` - reverts the whole commit, all the 10 files will be reverted

`git reset --mixed HEAD~` - takes the index back to the previous commit but leaves the work tree as is

`git add` - only add the changes you want before committing

`git commit` - create a new commit

`git reset --hard` - clean-up your work tree and index from unwanted changes

Comment: @matt when you push the new commit, the relevant files will be removed on the remote too

Comment: The remote will refuse to accept the push, and if you force it, you’ll wreck everyone else’s life.

Comment: I see no reason why you'd need to force the push; what you see in my suggestion is only **adding** a new commit, this is not re-writing any shared/public history.