# Git restore files to previous commit

Tags: git, logging, checkout, reset

I'm doing some test, and I created a local repos to version some files.
I would like to restore all my files to their state at a previous commit.

Is it possible ?
I know that git checkout file restore a file to the current commit state. However I'm not sure if git checkout * do the same for all file, and even more here I'm not sure if it's possible to restore from more than just the latest commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command.

```
git log
git checkout <commit_hash>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one previous commit and you have done some local changes without committing again, and you want to go back to the "checkpoint" (commit):

`git reset --hard HEAD`

You don't even need to know any commit hash, it will just bring you back to your HEAD, deleting everything that happened after.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out the answer posted here:[Chris Lloyd's answer to: How can I reset or revert a file to a specific revision?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/373848/12815795)

Here's a quick summary of his answer:

1. Enter the command `git log` in your terminal to find a list of all your commits.
2. Find the second to last commit's hash (here's an example: 72ba15b8de0c7689d0819136917f61e6f9715c2a)
3. `git diff <commit hash> <filename>`
4. `git reset <commit hash> <filename>`
5. `git checkout <commit hash>`

You should now be inside your former commit files.