# How to restore files from previous commit?

Tags: git

I find my commit where I deleted 10 files. After that, I committed a couple of times. NOw I only want to get these 10 files back on my branch

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```

shows

```
    Deleted 10 TIP files

 delete mode 100644 test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/INT/api-service TIP [Common]/INT_COMMON.json
 delete mode 100644 test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/INT/api-service TIP [Xamarin]/INT_XAMARIN_ANDROID.json
 delete mode 100644 test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/INT/api-service TIP [Xamarin]/INT_XAMARIN_IOS.json
 delete mode 100644 test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/INT/api-service TIP [iOS]/INT_IOS_BitBucket.json
 delete mode 100644 test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/INT/api-service TIP [iOS]/INT_IOS_GitHub.json
 delete mode 100644 test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/PROD/api-service TIP [Common]/PROD_COMMON.json
 delete mode 100644 test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/PROD/api-service TIP [Xamarin]/PROD_XAMARIN_ANDROID.json
 delete mode 100644 test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/PROD/api-service TIP [Xamarin]/PROD_XAMARIN_IOS.json
 delete mode 100644 test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/PROD/api-service TIP [iOS]/INT_IOS_BitBucket.json
 delete mode 100644 test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/PROD/api-service TIP [iOS]/INT_IOS_GitHub.json
```

I tried

```
git checkout 525afffc8641671f9fe2c33b68dc211ed20d0ec8 -- "test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/INT/api-service TIP [Common]/INT_COMMON.json"
```

but got error with path

```
error: pathspec 'test-runner/src/v2/Avalanche.TestRunner.BuildsScenarios/Configuration/INT/api-service' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

If I go for

```
    git checkout 525afffc8641671f9fe2c33b68dc211ed20d0ec8
HEAD is now at 525afffc864 Deleted 10 TIP files
```

What next?

How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reset or revert a file to a specific revision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-can-i-reset-or-revert-a-file-to-a-specific-revision)

Comment: As you can see error clearly cuts the path to file on encountering space character, you need to somehow indicate that spaces are part of the name. Try putting the "test-runner [...] .json" inside quotation marks.

Comment: @matszwecja I got the same with quotation marks.

Comment: @MikiBelavista That's impossible; the error info can by no means be the same with quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `525afffc86...` is the commit where you deleted the files.

If such is the case, the files do not exist in that commit, which is why you get the `did not match any file(s) known to git` error, they exist in the *parent* commit :

```
# <commit-ish>^ points to the parent of target commit :
git checkout 525afffc^ -- "test-runner/src/v2/ ... /INT_COMMON.json"
```