# Git How to checkout file from specific commit

Tags: git

I made some changes. Now after several commits and probably merges I want to revert a specific file back to a particular commit state in the workspace.

What is an appropriate git command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/215718/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+restore+file+old+commit

Answer (score 8):

You can revert a particular commit's state of the file back to the workspace with the following git command:

```
git checkout <COMMIT#> <relative/path/to/your/file>
```

Example:

```
git checkout 22864c16a5647d3b4ccb034aa5698f196a648a38 Gemfile
```

Comment: Although `git checkout` is perfectly fine for the job, you can now also mention `git restore` : `git restore -W -s 22864c16a -- path/to/file`

Comment: Before you get crazy: if you want to restore a file which was deleted in commit abc1234, run `git restore abc1234^ path/to/file`. In the commit itself the file is not there anymore ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can execute:

```
git checkout 0e97a7045e0b234efe5062600905468430ede879
```

The aproach above will move the pointer to this commit, but the branch will appears with the name like  (HEAD detached at 147e81b7), **or** you can will to path .git\refs\reads find your branch and change the UUID there for your hash commit. This approach is the better IMO. To a single file you can execute the command line like @Roman sad

```
git checkout 22864c16a5647d3b4ccb034aa5698f196a648a38 Gemfile
```

Comment: git checkout 0e97a7045e0b234efe5062600905468430ede879 goes not to the point of the question