# Lost File's Contents in Git: How Can I Recover Them?

Tags: git, github, version-control, file-recovery

A few months ago I finished up a project and pushed to git (using Github). Then I came back to the code a couple weeks ago and noticed the files I pushed with my last commit were empty, they were all there, but empty.

Since this was the very last commit, I don't have any history except that last commit. I've searched through git log, reflog, and stashes to find the contents but found none of the file's contents. I'm very confused how this would've happened, I wouldn't have pushed empty files. I never deleted the code locally, but I did pull once since then since I made Readme changes on another computer (before I noticed the missing file contents). Is there anything else I should try?

I should've pushed more and made backups, but here we are. Now daily file history is being saved to another disk.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by _"Since this was the very last commit, I don't have any history except that last commit."_? What can you tell that you _do_ have in the repository? Does `git log --oneline --graph --all` provide any output?

Comment: Are you using git-lfs by any chance?

Comment: @Brian61354270 I don't have any history of the files that are empty, it looks like I just pushed a bunch of empty python files. All other files before that commit are completely fine, it was just the last push those new files created were empty. That command shows me the commits from both branches and when they were forked and merged (didn't know that exists thanks!), but still don't see anything helpful about the empty files, I've looked at the logs from those commits. I'm not using git-lfs.

Comment: Great, that command is showing you the history from the current revision. You can try checking out any of the commits before the merge with `git switch --detach <rev>` where `<rev>` is a commit hash. If you ever commited a non-empty version of those files, you should be able to find a commit with their contents. Once you find a commit with the file contents you want, take note of the commit id, switch back to whichever branch you want to continue from (`git switch <branch>`), and then run `git restore --source=<rev> <path>` where `<rev>` is the commit from earlier and `<path>` is a file path

Comment: See also [How can I reset or revert a file to a specific revision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/215718/11082165)